# What the expected value of $X$, $E(X)$, if the joint pdf $f(x,y) = \frac{e^{-y}}{y} $ for values $0 < x < y,\ 0 < y < \infty$?

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus

What is $E(X)$ if the joint PDF of $X$ and $Y$ is

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{e^{-y}}{y}, &0 < x < y, \ 0 < y < \infty\\
0, &\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$

$$E(X) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x f_X(x)\,dx$$

$$f_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)\,dy = \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-y}}{y} \,dy$$

But I'm not sure how to compute the integral for $f_X(x).$

So I tried to compute the entire double integral $E(X).$

$$E(X) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x f_X(x)\,dx =\int_{0}^{y}x\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-y}}{y}\, dy .$$

I remember there is a trick to swap the bounds of integration so that it can make integration easier, but I'm confused how to do this.

Comment: The integral diverges at $y\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: If you need formal derivation, you can follow the answer below for integration. If you are familiar with the distribution, actually it is easy to see that $X|Y = y \sim \text{Uniform}(0, y)$ and $Y \sim \text{Exp}(1)$. Therefore $E[X] = E[E[X|Y]] = E[Y/2] = 1/2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us rewrite the joint probability density function (PDF) under the form
$$
f_{(X,Y)}(x,y) = \frac{e^{-y}}{y} \boldsymbol{1}_{0<x<y} \, .
$$
Integrating with respect to $y$ gives the PDF $f_X$ of $X$:
$$
f_X(x) = \int_\mathbb{R} f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)\, dy = \boldsymbol{1}_{x>0}\int_{x}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-y}}{y}\, dy = -\text{Ei}(-x)\, \boldsymbol{1}_{x>0} \, ,
$$
where $\text{Ei}$ is the exponential integral function. The expected value of $X$ is
$$
\mathbb{E}X = \int_\mathbb{R} x f_X(x)\, dx = \int_0^\infty -x \text{Ei}(-x)\, dx = \frac{1}{2}.
$$
This result can be obtained by integrating
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}X = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} x f_{(X,Y)}(x,y) \, dx\, dy &= \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-y}}{y} \int_0^y x \, dx\, dy \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty y e^{-y}\, dy\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \, .
\end{aligned}
If the function is integrable over the domain of integration, then it does not matter along which variable integration is performed first (Fubini's theorem).